# Proof ultrafilter theorem without axiom of choice?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, axiom-of-choice, filters

[This](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~alopez-o/math-faq/mathtext/node35.html) is stated that: the ultrafilter theorem can't be proved without the axiom of choice in Zermelo-Fraenkel.

> Is this true? Axiom of choice implies ultrafilter theorem but why is it not possible to prove ultrafilter theorem without axiom of
>   choice?

The ultrafilter theorem written in link: *Every Boolean algebra has an ultrafilter on it.*

> Is it same as: *Every filter can be extended to an ultrafilter*?

Here filter is subset of power set. But in partial orders:

> And is *Every filter can be extended to an ultrafilter* for sets same
>   as *Every filter on poset can be extended to ultrafilter* ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement at the link is at best rather misleading. The ultrafilter theorem ($\mathsf{UT}$) is strictly weaker than the axiom of choice: if $\mathsf{ZF}$ is consistent, so is $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{UT}+\neg\mathsf{AC}$. (And the result that the union of countably many countable sets is countable is a lot weaker than $\mathsf{AC}$, though it does not follow from $\mathsf{ZF}$ alone.)

If ‘cannot be proved in $\mathsf{ZF}$ without $\mathsf{AC}$’ means simply ‘cannot be proved in $\mathsf{ZF}$’, the statement is true. If it means that $\mathsf{AC}$ is required in order to prove $\mathsf{UT}$, then it’s false, since $\mathsf{UT}$ can hold in models in which $\mathsf{AC}$ is false.

Comment: Thank you!!! And is the UT for filter on sets the same as the UT for filter on poset?

Comment: @dolan: It definitely has the same strength as the UT for Boolean algebras; I’d have to think a bit about the situation for posets in general.

Comment: @dolan: It should be okay, since you can embed a poset in a Boolean algebra.

Comment: Thank you!!! And is it true that it is impossible to prove UT without axiom of choice? (It is stated in link)

Comment: @dolan: As I said, it is possible to have a model of set theory in which UT is true and AC is false; one can prove that UT holds in that model without using AC in that model. What the author of that web page really means, I think, is simply that you can’t prove UT just from ZF; the only more or less standard axiomatization of set theory from which one can prove UT is ZFC.

Comment: Many thank you Brian!

Comment: @dolan: You’re welcome!

Comment: @Brian The linked page is not wrong, at least not currently.  It says that the ultrafilter theorem "depend[s] on AC (i.e., [it] cannot be proved in ZF without AC)" and I think the worst you can say about this is that it says something ambiguous and then clarifies it in the next sentence.

Comment: @Trevor: I read *cannot be proved in ZF without AC* to mean *cannot be proved without the use of AC*; if the author of the page meant *cannot be proved in ZF alone, i.e., ZF not including AC*, then it’s merely very misleadingly worded.

Comment: @Brian It is not optimally worded, yes, but "[it] cannot be proved in ZF without AC" is definitely true, because the negation of this statement is definitely false.

Comment: @Trevor: That depends entirely on exactly what is meant by *cannot be proved in ZF without AC*, and it’s the interpretation of that statement that is at issue.

Comment: @Brian I think it is the negation of "can be proved in ZF without AC"

Comment: @Trevor: It may have done, but in that case the phrase *without AC* is wholly redundant, so I did not interpret it that way (and neither, it seems clear, did the OP). However, I’ve amended my answer to try to clear up the point a bit.

Comment: @Brian Ok, thanks.  +1

Comment: I bumped the question for retagging; so while at it, I fixed a typo here.